# Using the spread operator on Iterable gives `Array [ Array Iterator ]`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nrwl-nx

We recently moved our react project over to nx, and in the process, something weird is now happening with spread operators. I am doing the following

```
[...Array(someNumber).keys()]
```

which should give `[0,1,2,...,someNumber-1]` however when I log the result I get `Array [ Array Iterator ]`

I have had the same problems when I try and do `[...someMap.entries()]`.

I suspected it might be a problem with Babel, but have tried using both `@babel/plugin-transform-spread` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` with no luck. We are using the following presets in our react app

```
"presets": [
    [
      "@nrwl/react/babel",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Also, I don't know if this is related, but now we also get an error when using `someString.replace` saying `Uncaught TypeError: someString.replace is not a function`

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

Comment: definitely some issue with your configuration, seems to work fine in browser console

Comment: Did you see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-spread#options?

Comment: @Bergi yeah i did, and tried all combinations

Comment: Setting `loose: false` or [`iterableIsArray: false`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/assumptions#iterableisarray) should fix this. Did you have a look at the transpiler output? What code does it generate? Does the code change when you change these options?

Comment: Also, what nodejs version are you using that doesn't support spread syntax and iterators?

Comment: Setting `loose: false` does not work, and the spread operator works fine if I do it in the console

Comment: I use node 16.13.0